# Can a cloud service talk to an ARM VM in azure?

Tags: azure

I was trying to enable disk encryption for a classic VM but then found out that it is not possible since it is a classic resource.

But all my services are deployed on classic cloud services. So I was thinking since an ARM VM can have disk encryption capability, maybe I can move my disks to an ARM VM. But I don't know if my application would still be able to communicate and do the read/write with the ARM VM since it will be in its own ARM Vnet.

The VM basically has a mongo server running inside it and that's why the application or the cloud services need to be able to communicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you have VMs in Classic Mode, and you want to move one of them to ARM Mode to enable encryption on the VM, but you don't want to move all of your VMs and you don't want to lose connectivity between the ARM and Classic Vnets.

If the above summry is correct, then you should use **Azure Vnet Peering**.

> Virtual network (VNet) peering enables you to connect two VNets in the
>   same region through the Azure backbone network. Once peered, the two
>   VNets appear as one for connectivity purposes. The two VNets are still
>   managed as separate resources, but virtual machines (VM) in the peered
>   VNets can communicate with each other directly by using private IP
>   addresses.

Beware of the limitations though:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, we can create a **VPN gateway** connection over an IPsec/IKE VPN tunnel between the virtual networks(ASM Vnet and ARM Vnet).

We can create a **VNet-to-VNet connection** between classic Vnet and  ARM vnet. More information about connect virtual networks from different deployment models using the portal, please refer to the [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-connect-different-deployment-models-portal).

**[VNet peering](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview)** is another way to create a connection between your VNets and has some connection advantages for certain configurations.